# Using AntiXss methods in C# - .Net4.5

Tags: c#, encoding, .net-4.5, xss, antixsslibrary

**I have a few questions regarding how to use AntiXss in my .Net project (not an MVC project. Traditional .Net project and contains .aspx and .ascx web pages).**

**1)** Is my following approach correct :-
My initial code in aspx.cs file (without AntiXss) :

```
int ID;
 if (int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["ID"], out ID))
  {
                  IDHdn.Value = ID.ToString();
                  IDLbl.Text = IDHdn.Value;
   }
```

My current code in aspx.cs file (after implementing AntiXss) :

```
using System.Web.Security.AntiXss;

 int ID;
 if (int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["ID"], out ID))
  {
                  IDHdn.Value = ID.ToString();
                  IDLbl.Text = AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(IDHdn.Value,true);
   }
```

**Is this the correct approach? When is HtmlDecode required? Will it be required in my case?**
.
.
.
.

**2)** Which AntiXss method to use for encoding Request.Form values?

For e.g)

```
string nameList = Request.Form["name"];
```

**How to encode above code using AntiXss library?**

Currently I'm simply doing the following :

```
string nameList = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Request.Form["name"]);
```

How to do the same using AntiXss library?

.
.
.
.

**3)** **Will adding the following in web.config affect other encoders being used (like HttpUtility) in my application?**

```
  <httpRuntime encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder" />
```

....

**4)** **What's the difference between :**

```
  IDLbl.Text = AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(IDHdn.Value,true); //true
```

and

```
  IDLbl.Text = AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(IDHdn.Value,false); //false
```

Comment: What are `IDHdn` and `IDLbl`? Are you using Webforms? MVC? WebAPI?

Comment: IDHdn is an ASP HiddenField while IDLbl is an ASP Label.

Comment: It's not MVC. Simple WebForms with .aspx and .ascx pages.